# If comparison in make file

Tags: makefile, aix

I have a makefile. I need to check the exit status of a command and the performing comparison, if exit status is 0 then perform some display action. But i am getting the same message if its success or failure for both the scenario.

Please find the below code and Help me what is the right way to do this:-

```
FILES = test1.sh test2.sh
manoj: $(FILES)
        ls  $(FILES)
        $(eval exitstatus="$(shell echo $$?)")
        @echo $(exitstatus)
        ifeq (0,$(exitstatus))
         $(error something going wrong..........)
        endif
clean:  pwd
```

Getting same output as :

```
testmake.mk:4: *** something going wrong...........  Stop.
```

for both ifeq ifeq (0,$(exitstatus))  and ifneq ifeq (0,$(exitstatus))

I want to perform some action if the condition is success otherwise nothing want to do.

Comment: FILES = test1.sh test2.sh
tdodbc: $(FILES)
        ls  $(FILES)
        $(eval exitstatus="$(shell echo $$?)")
        @echo $(exitstatus)
        ifeq (0,$(exitstatus))
         $(error something going wrong..........)
        endif
clean:  pwd

Comment: Each line of the recipe is executed in a separate shell; the status from the `ls` command isn't available to the next line unless you use `; \` to extend the recipe over multiple lines. Additionally, if the `ls` commands generates a non-zero exit status, the actions stop anyway, so the extra testing shown is spurious (unnecessary, shall we say).  I think there's an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) lurking here. What are you trying to do? (There are ways to disrupt operations — `-`, `.IGNORE:` or `.ONESHELL`).  But they've not been mentioned so they probably aren't a factor.)

Comment: Hi Jonathan,

if i am executing the below code then i can able to capture the exit status as belo:-

FILES = test1.sh test2.sh

status = "0"

tdodbc: $(FILES)

        ls  $(FILES)

        $(eval exitstatus="$(shell echo $$?)")

        @echo $(exitstatus)
clean:  pwd
-------------------------------------
Output :-
ls  test1.sh test2.sh
test1.sh  test2.sh
0

Comment: And if after that i want to do some  comparison with  the exit status of "exitstatus"  with some other variable can you please share some sudo code to perform this requirement because I am new to makefile creation.

Comment: Please don't try putting code into comments — edit the information into your question where you can format it.  Then leave a comment indicating that you've done so with the `@Jonathan` notation.  I'll try to take a look, but no promises on when.

Answer (score 0):

In the recipe shell commands are used, not `make` directives.

And when target's recipe is executed that means all its prerequisites do exist:

```
manoj: $(FILES)
    @echo "$(FILES) do exist at this point."
```